# high frequency (0.01 sec) realoadAt call for UICollectionview bumps cpu usage to 100%

Tags: swift, uikit

I am looking to call collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(item: middle, section: 0)]) at frequency of 0.01 second to just update single cell, but it bumps cpu usage to 100%.

Any suggestion is welcome to bring it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do that, just need to get the cell at indexPath you want:

```swift
if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: 10, section: 0)) as? `YourCollectionViewCellClass` {
    //Update cell data here instead of reloading
}
```

Comment: Great, cellForItem reduced cpu usage drastically.
But now I trapped in another issue,   I have an array as datasource, so I update middle item of array and append new item at end of array, so effectively my datasource size increases but collectionview still knows old datasource (array) count, so on scroll collection view does not create cell to populate newly added items in array. 
so how can I update collectionview datasource count ?

 realoadAt api was used to call "func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int " to update DS count

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @son above about not doing this is absolutely correct. You should ask collectionView for existing cell instance at an indexPath and do the changes manually there.

It's such a common problem that starting `iOS 15` we have system APIs to do above for us.
[UICollectionView.reconfigureItems](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/3801889-reconfigureitems)

[image]

Comment: yeah As mentioned above cellForItem reduced cpu usage. But now I trapped in another issue, I have an array as datasource, so I update middle item of array and append new item at end of array, so effectively my datasource size increases but collectionview still knows old datasource (array) count, so on scroll collection view does not create cell to populate newly added items in array. so how can I update collectionview datasource count ? realoadAt api was used to call "func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int " to update DS count

Comment: @AmitSingh You should ask a new question for the second problem.